# Without scale-out, does NoSQL have better performance than MySQL?

Tags: database, nosql

I have a single machine for setting up a database. The main purpose of that database is to write/write audit log. The write/read ratio is about 9:1. Originally I planed to use MySQL. Later I heard of NoSQL DB have better performance on when "scale out". I am interested if I only have 1 single machine, will NoSQL DB (eg, cassandra or mongo DB) have better performance than MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.
I am using MongoDB. I tried my application on both MySQL and MongoDB. I see better performance on MongoDB.
So, in general I have noticed better performance.
But I think it depends on certain factors such as if you are using join, foreign keys etc. As you must be knowing in NoSQL there are usually no joins etc.

PS: Having said all this. It depends on how and what you are doing.
Also, if you are using MongoDB as your NoSQL Database, do check the newer version (3.0) as they say it is 10 times faster than their older version (2.6).

And if you really need a high performance database you can go for **Redis**.
It's a "NoSQL" key-value data store. More precisely, it is a data structure server. Not like MongoDB (which is a disk-based document store), though MongoDB could be used for similar key/value use cases. The closest analog is probably to think of Redis as Memcached, but with built-in persistence (snapshotting or journaling to disk) and more datatypes.

You will need to read a bit about it to make a decision on what is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

It **really** depends on your usage scenario.  In general, NoSQL solutions tend to provide simpler semantics which, in theory at least, can avoid some of the overhead of ACID-compliant SQL solutions.  In practice though the real world performance can be affected by so many factors that the theory rarely comes into play.

On a single box, you are probably better off spending time on optimizing your code to work with whatever platform you choose.

There are "textbook" solutions for dealing with log data - ElasticSearch/Kibana/LogStash is a common one, Redis is another - are usually focused on larger scale systems and don't fit your single-machine requirement.

Depending on how much you are willing to invest, you may be able to squeeze the most IOPS out of your box when using a really thin storage mechanism such as ESENT or BerkeleyDB. Word of warning though: those are really more painful to work with.

In summary, I'll repeat myself: On a single box, you are probably better off spending time on optimizing your code to work with whatever platform you choose.

Answer (score 0):

One of the in-memory NoSQL databases with persistence is the best choice for your scenario. They do write operations extremely fast because a write operation under the hood there is just a write to the end of the write ahead log file, which can be done at speed up to 100mb/sec even on magnetic disks.

Try **Redis** or **Tarantool**. The latter is better if you have a heavy concurrent write load.